# How to study mathematics

Tags: soft-question, self-learning, advice

I've been self studying math for 6 months, i'm a computer engineering student and I just know a little bit of calculus, linear algebra, abstract algebra, logic, set theory, but not much at all, my problem is that i'm never satisfied, even if maybe "I know a lot" (for example I read 4 logic books cover to cover) in my head I always feel like I still dont get it. I would like understand when someone reaches this famous "mathematical maturity" and really understand a topic. I was used to studying calculus which was pretty much all about computation and I could consider myself ready to move on with the chapter when I could solve most of the exercises, right now i'm studying set theory and most of the exercises are only proofs (with no solutions unfortunately) and I can't really test myself to see if I really get the topic or not, unless it's all about proving things but I doubt it. So my question is, how do you study a math book? Usually I can test myself with other subjects solving problems etc (physics, chemistry etc), but what about math? When should I consider myself ready to move on to the next topic?

Comment: I guess somehow mathematics is indeed "all" about proving things. That's what most advanced math students and researchers are doing. Have you tried to read something in analysis? Personally, I picked up most "mathematical maturity" when first moving from calculus to analysis. One way I used to check if I should move on to next topics is to redo the proofs on books myself and attempted some exercises. When you are actually "doing" math proofs yourself, you may understand more things than simply reading them.

Comment: @JKDASF well, actually I studied "analysis" but here in Europe calculus doesn't really exists, they just call it analysis, to make things "worse" I said calculus, but I've never really tried to prove things on my own without memorizing by heart the proof (unfortunately)

Comment: I am problem oriented. I learn about new math topics because I hope to be able to use them to solve some actual problem I am working on. This helps a lot, because I always have something to directly apply the stuff I read, and this makes me understand it way better. But, yes, at the end it's all about proofs from some point on (and definitions and being able to express questions). But if you work on an actual problem, you might really, really want to prove something, or learn how to actually formulate your stuff such that you can prove something. And that's how you learn best.

Comment: @ciwodol Oh that's good. Try to actually do proofs by yourself. That's what my teachers advised me and I always found it helpful. But also I think that depends on why you want to study math. For helping solve problems in your field or just for enrichment or other things. Anyway, good luck on your study.

Comment: Proofs are an essential part of mathematics. That's the way we know something is true and most importantly *why* it is true. So, if you're able to prove something, that means that you have a deep understading of the topic. Proving a theorem is like solving a problem, trying to prove it requires trying different approaches, interpreting things in different ways... so you will really learn a lot of the mathematical experience and of the mathematical content by doing proofs.

Comment: @Javi Yeah well, I never skip proofs and I always try to understand them, but I think coming up with a proof is not so so important, often it's all about "knowing a little trick" or just applying a few theorems just stated

Comment: reading is not useful to get understanding... what is useful is to make A LOT of exercises AND know in deep the reason for the existence of some theorem or mathematical theory, it context, what solves, etc... Of course you need to know how to prove every theorem you read, or at least have a picture about how to prove it, the ideas behind the proof, etc.

Comment: @ciwodol coming up with proofs is essential if you want to feel mathematical "maturity". Coming up with proofs means being able to develop mathematical ideas and giving your intuition shape. It's not the only thing in mathematics, but it's definitely unskippable.

Comment: (continue...) mathematics is almost the same that going to a gym: you need to practice it many times in a week to stay in good form, it need to be maintained over time, it is not something that you "acquire", you need to hold it working on it. It is a life style or part of it. If you dont practice it regularly you lost it because the connection between concepts and the memory related to it can be lost over time. The understanding is not "free", it doesn't comes just reading (at least in the majority of cases) because mathematics is mainly very abstract: you need to work to acquire it

Comment: And by the way, 6 months is very little time. I think I needed years to feel that I am a mathematician, or at least that I could think like a mathematician.

Comment: @Javi Thanks a lot for you answers, really, I haven't been studying math for 6 months, I actually started 5 years ago, but as I said, being a computer engineering student I studied other subjects as well and so I haven't practiced only math, but in the last 6 months I've been studying it by myself everyday after college, but I feel like i'm missing something, like a way to understand if i'm really understanding or not. i guess i will try to prove more things for now on

Comment: There are some exercise that are just there to check that you understand the definitions correctly. Other exercises are more challenging and interesting. Both kinds of exercises are important, but the last group will give you a more accurate feeling of how being a mathematician is.

Answer (score 1):

The first question you seem to be asking is what constitutes a "mathematically mature" understanding of a field of mathematics. Understanding math fundamentally requires understanding proofs. To truly comprehend a field of mathematics, you should be able to understand the proofs of the most fundamental theorems in the field and be able to apply these theorems and variations of their proofs to other problems in the field. This makes understanding mathematics at a high level both challenging and rewarding.

Thus, the real question is how to master proofs. For beginners, this really amounts to recognising that their own proofs are either correct or incorrect. There are two answers to this question which, depending on how you look at the situation, are either competing or complementary.

The first way is to master the notion of "formal proof". A formal proof is basically a sequence of statements, each of which is expressed in formal logic, and each of which follows from the previous ones by an application of a single formal logic rule (or is an axiom). Obviously, nobody actually writes proofs of any nontrivial complexity this way. However, if you understand formal proofs, you'll be able to see how to take a proof and (at least in principle) translate it into formal logic. Thus, the test of whether a proof is correct is simply whether it can be translated into formal logic. According to this school of thought, the key when writing an informal proof is that at every step of the way, you are able to understand from the informal proof how that portion of the formal proof would be written.

The other way is by writing proofs to be read by other people. A well-written proof under this definition is one that convinces a competent mathematician that the statement is proved. Mastering proofs using this method requires that you have someone to check your work and point out where things should be made clearer.

Once you understand how to recognise a correct proof and how in principle to write one, mastering a particular field will require you to learn certain theorems and techniques which come up over and over again in the field. For example, when learning real analysis, there are quite a few proofs involving taking an interval and repeatedly splitting it in half (for example, the intermediate value theorem). At a higher level, proofs in real analysis will involve more general concepts like connectedness and compactness.

At the highest level of abstraction, category theory provides techniques which prove extremely helpful in most (if not all) branches of math; many theorems across disparate fields of math often prove to be special cases of a theorem from category theory. For example, Stone-Cech compactification and free groups are examples of the same categorical phenomenon; a left adjoint to a forgetful functor. The existence of both of these follows from the Adjoint Functor Theorem.

At the end of the day, mathematicians spend years attaining this "mathematical maturity". Don't be discouraged if it takes longer than six months. If you really want to master mathematics, focus on proofs and take your time. Don't go on to the next chapter in the book until you can prove every theorem in the chapter and can work every exercise. If you had somehow mastered linear algebra, set theory, logic, abstract algebra, and calculus in just six months while also studying computer engineering, you would be a prodigy. Don't burn yourself out; learning is a marathon, not a sprint.

Comment: IMHO I disagree: to me its not enough to understand proofs and know the ideas behind them to understand in deep some mathematical topic, it is also necessary to know the **context** of these theorems and related definitions, they motivation, the history where it born, the problems that want to solve, they applications, etc. You need the big picture to understand what something is (in mathematics and any other thing) what is it meaning, and proofs cannot give it, no matter how good someone understand the related proofs and it variations. In short: you cannot reduce understanding to logic.